# Is valarray<valarray<built-in type> > safe?

Tags: c++

After reading this http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2000-q1/msg00123.html, it seems that using a valarray of valarrays is not guaranteed by the standard to be safe. But when I read the list of requirements (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) for T in valarray, it seems that T=valarray`<built-in type>` satisfy all of them. Is `valarray<valarray<built-in type> >` safe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not safe.

In particular, `valarray` can throw<sup>1</sup> under some circumstances (e.g., see §26.6.1/6), but if the type you put into a valarray throws (ever), you get undefined behavior (§26.2/2).

It's mostly unnecessary anyway. valarray supports 2D addressing via slices.

---

<sub>1. Note: it's allowed to throw, but never directly required to do so. At the same time, many operations on non-const valarrays are required to return entire an entire new valarray, which involves dynamic allocation. If that fails, there seems to be little choice but to throw an exception.</sub>

Comment: What do you think of Forever's answer? Seems convincing to me as a product of language evolution. The odd formatting indicates a footnote, which he quoted faithfully.

Comment: Isn't this inconsistent with the *intention* as expressed by footnote 275 "and instantiations of valarray for value types" as quoted in ForEveR's answer (I haven't looked up the standard)? Yes I know that footnotes and examples are not normative. But they tend to express intent.

Comment: This answer seems to be different from the one offered in the mailing list.

Comment: I think Forever's answer reflects something that was probably intended, but when you get down to it probably bordered on delusional. In particular, valarrays allocate memory dynamically, and many operations on non-const valarrays allocate entire new vallarays. When/if those dynamic allocations fail, your only real choices are some sort of zombie object, or else throwing an exception. I don't see anything in the standard that allows the zombie object approach.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: thanks! now, if this were a newsgroup, we'd now be discussing who coined the term "zombie object". :-) i remember having to explain it to others in clc++m, but i think i picked it up from andrei.

Comment: @Alf: Zombies come from coffins, so I probably coined it. :-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin Suppose that if valarrays don't throw, does it satisfy all the requirements?

Comment: @ggg: Yes, at least as far as I know, other than throwing, they should be all right.